# Is there an Android library like RoboGuice for Dagger?

Tags: android, roboguice, dagger-2

I'm in the process of switching my app over from RoboGuice to Dagger.  RoboGuice has this nice feature where you can inject native components (@Inject Context mContext gives you a Context object).  I was wondering if anyone knew of an extension to Dagger or another DI library that can do this.  Thanks!

Comment: May I ask you why you are switching to Dagger? Just out of interest.

Comment: you can do the same via dagger

Comment: I am changing because I want to play around with Dagger on a larger project to really see what the benefit is.  Also, it seems like an interesting challenge

Comment: do check http://androidannotations.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/142) thread on the Dagger issues list, you can accomplish this behavior but you need to inject it via a module, as discussed [here](https://plus.google.com/+AlexeyZakharovVladimirovich/posts/a7TH12cQLEa)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's too easy with Dagger, so there is no need in this feature out-of-the box.

Moreover, you can specifically control which context to inject, it's really useful to inject activity context under its scope.